# LWJGL Black Screen on Mac

Tags: java, macos, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I am unable to draw anything onto the screen on Mac OSX Mavericks using LWJGL 2.9.1. I made a window that uses OpenGL version 3.3 and I am trying to use #version 330 for my shaders. All I get is a black screen.

I am using a vbo and ibo to draw something:

```
public void draw()
{
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 8 * 4, 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 8 * 4, 12);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 8 * 4, 20);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
}
```

This method is called every render cycle where vbo contains an array of vertices, ibo contains an array of indices and vertex attributes 0, 1, and 2 are position, texCoord and normal respectively. However, I don't know how helpful this will be since this just a small portion of my code.

The main problem is that I am getting a black screen and don't know why. I get no errors and I did set up the context to use OpenGL version 3.3. The thing that confuses me the most is that the exact same code works perfectly fine on Windows 7, on the same computer and the mesh that I am drawing shows up on the screen just fine as expected. It must be a Mac problem or I'm not setting up something correctly.

If you need me to post my vertex and fragment shader or any other pieces of code I will gladly put them up.

Comment: You definitely are doing things all wrong for Core 3.3. You should be using VAOs instead of setting up these states every draw call and then disabling them after the draw call. In fact, if you do not have a least *some* VAO bound in a Core profile context, then `glDrawElements (...)` is an invalid operation.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks! I am now using a VAO and it works fine. But if glDrawElements is an invalid operation, why does it work without using VAOs on Windows 7??

Comment: Probably because you do not have a core profile in Windows.